# How can I repair a section of carpet that a cat scratched up?

Tags: repair, replacement, carpet, damage

Much to my displeasure, my (wife's) cat has torn up a large section (2'x6') of carpet. Eventually we would like to sell the house and this would definitely be noticed. Is there any way to repair the carpet or should I plan to sell the house with the damage as is, or replace the carpet in a single room which is likely to be a different color than the rest of the house.

Comment: Do you have a picture? I would think that the answer would depend on the extent of the damage and where exactly it is.

Comment: If you have some spare carpet you could cut out the damaged part and replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the wonders of carpet ...

The answer is that you would be able to replace the carpet in that area, typically seamlessly, if you have more of the same carpet, such as remnants that the installers left in your attic or garage. If you don't have more of the SAME carpet -- as in, same batch, same manufacturing date, same everything -- then you will end up replacing the carpet, or giving the buyer an allowance to replace carpet as part of the closing/sale costs.

Comment: Due to wear and fade, you may not be able to repair the carpet seamlessly.